Proof of Theorem 5.38 in Morters and Peres' Brownian Motions book
In the proof of Theorem 5.38 which states that if $\tau_{a}$ is the hitting time of $a>0$ and if $\sigma_{a}=\inf\{t\geq 0:B(t)\geq |a|\}$, then $\int_{0}^{\tau_{a}}\mathbf{1}_{\{0\leq B(t)\leq a\}}\,dt$ has the same distribution as $\sigma_{a}$, Morters and Peres uses the a lemma which states that if $\displaystyle s(t)=\int_{0}^{t}\mathbf{1}_{B(s)\geq 0}$ and if $t(s)=\inf\{t\geq 0:s(t)\geq s\}$ be the right continuous inverse, then $\{B(t(s)):s\geq 0\}$ has same distribution as $\{|B(s)|:s\geq 0\}$.
To prove this, he says that by removing the negative excursions from a simple random walk leads to a reflected simple random walk. (1)
and thus, he says that for the embedded random walk $S_{n}^{*}$ inside the brownian motion (by Skorokhod's Theorem), we have that $S_{n}^{*}(t(s,S_{n}))_{s\geq0}$ has same distribution as $(|S_{n}^{*}(s)|)_{s\geq 0}$ for $s(t,f)=\int_{0}^{t}\mathbf{1}_{f(s)\geq 0}\,ds$.
My questions:
(1) what does he mean by "removing the negative excursions" ? Can someone give me an explicit expression for what this removal means? For example, what do we replace the portions of the negative excursions by?
(2). How is the right continuous inverse play a part in establishing that $S_{n}^{*}(t(s,S_{n}))_{s\geq0}$ has same distribution as $(|S_{n}^{*}(s)|)_{s\geq 0}$ and how does it at all follow from "removing negative excursions"?
(3) Can someone provide me an intuitive explanation on how this right continuous inverse is acting? I am familiar with generalized inverse of CDF's but this is entirely new to me.
Since, Professor @YuvalPeres is often active on this site, it would be really wonderful if he can take a look at this question.
Here is a link to the book I am referring to which is generally considered the go to reference for Brownian Motions.
